# Missing [mx.rpc]::IResponder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to use the Flex 4 SDK's mx.rpc package in a Flash application.
I imported Flex's rpc.swc (Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\frameworks\libs\rpc.swc) into my project by adding it to the list in Flash's "Publish Settings/Flash/ActionScrip 3.0 Settings/Library Path". It seems like I have access to the classes, however when I compile I get this error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.rpc]::IResponder.
```

There's no location or line for the error either. Any idea how to get this to work? TIA!

Notes:
I'm using Flash Builder 4 and Flash CS5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing the rpc.swc wasn't enough. I added the entire Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\frameworks\libs\ folder to the library path, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The IResponder Interface is included in the framework.swc. That one and rpc.swc should be enough if those are the only flex features you are using.

Comment: This helped me, thanks!  However - I do wonder how the heck you are supposed to know that `mx.rpc.IResponder` is in `framework.swc`.  The namespace and [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/IResponder.html) _both_ imply it is in `rpc.swc` (or even `mx.swc`).