# asSQL API - 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.rpc]::IResponder

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to use an external swc that someone made off the net. It's a mysql driver for actionscript 3. https://code.google.com/p/assql/

Problem is, even after linking the swc in Adobe Flash CC under Actionscript 3 > Properties > Library path, I get an error saying it can't find [mx.rpc]::IResponder.

Does anyone have any experience with this lib or know what could be the problem? Is this due to me not using adobe flex? I found [Missing [mx.rpc]::IResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834986/missing-mx-rpciresponder) but that's saying I need a library from Adobe Flash Builder 4. Kind of rusty on compiler errors. [And the internet at my place has been limited as far as downstream goes, so it's about a 3 hour download to get it.]

Comment: I think that library is for Flex AIR apps.

Comment: So, would I just get a Flex SDK and add it to the library in Adobe Flash CC? Kind of silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by getting the [Flex SDK](http://[http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) and adding [pathtosdk]/framework/libs/ to the library path in Adobe Flash CC.